# Can't use NVIDIA Drivers and can't access windows C: and D: from ubuntu 18.04 after dual booting with windows

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

I have XPS 9570 16gb ram, 512 ssd and Geforce 1050 ti gpu. Just dual booted with windows and have kept swap area of 8gb and 65gb of root. I cant access Nvidia drivers and nor can i access windows drives.
[Image of Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPHyp.png)

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did you see?

Comment: I've tries using command "nvidia-smi", it showed me results as "Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nvidia-340      
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390", so i tried "sudo apt install nvidia-340" and it gave me result as "Package nvidia-340 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
"

Comment: Next I tried "sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390" and i got no errors and then again i tried "nvidia-smi" and it told me this "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
"

Comment: Try `sudo software-properties-gtk` and look under the 'Additional Drivers' tab.

Comment: This is what it shows as updated in question description.

Comment: I would just select then the Nvidia (proprietary,tested) driver and hit 'Apply Changes'.

Comment: I did that, doesn't work.

Comment: Errors? Run `journalctl -a -f` in a terminal window and then try again. Also, make sure "Proprietary drivers for devices" and "Software restricted by copyright" are selected under the Software&Updates "Ubuntu Software" tab.